# Why is some of my socket data getting overwritten with "3f" bytes?

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets

*I am using: Android Studio/Java 1.8 (Client) VS2010/.NET 4.0 (Server)*

This Java code is constantly sending invalid data:

```
long FileSize = 1131666;

byte [] fs = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putLong(FileSize).array();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write("FILE".getBytes());
baos.write(fs); //HERE
baos.write(GetHash().getHexStdstring().getBytes());
baos.write(dest_filename.getBytes());
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(baos.toByteArray());
out.flush();
```

This is what I get (viewed with wireshark):

```
46:49:4c:45: ("FILE")
3f:44:11:00:00:00:00:00: (1131583)
32:37:64:35:36:61:32:34:32:36:31:30:37:36:37:32:30:65:34:38:66:37:34:65:36:61:64:38:34:65:36:30:65:64:33:63:66:64:34:36:32:64:36:62:37:65:62:64:62:32:63:63:62:37:37:64:36:38:37:66:64:64:66:39:
5c:45:75:72:6f:70:65:2e:70:6e:67
```

And thus my C++ server app receives the value as `1131583`, but no matter what value I use as `FileSize`, I always seem to get a `3f` in there somewhere...

Another instance is when the FileSize is `22451663`, I get `3f:3f:56:01:00:00:00:00` (or `22429503`).

Any thoughts?

Weird thing is, if I translate `fs` back to a number or a string and Toast the value, just before it's sent, it says its correct.

Comment: If this is java why is it tagged c++?

Comment: Why the `ByteArrayOutputStream`? Just write it all straight the socket. Put a `BufferedOutputStream` in there if you want buffering.

Comment: @soulsabr - because my server app is written in c++

Comment: @EJP because I actually have a method Send() to do all that, I just compacted the code for a smaller question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the ISO-8859-1 character for `0x3f` is `?`, and it seems that because I was sending my constructed ByteArayOutputStream to my `Send(String string)` function, it was changing a lot of bytes to `0x3f`, like `0x92` which has no ISO-8859-1 character.

I changed my code to like so:

```
// in main code
Bytestring message = new Bytestring(baos.toByteArray());
Send(message);

// send function
public void Send(Bytestring string) {
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    // other code for writing header
    out.write(string.getBytes());
    out.flush();
}
```

Bytestring being a string class I created based on a byte array, instead of a String which is based on a (2-byte) char array.

Answer (score 1):

```
6:49:4c:45: ("FILE")
00:00:00:00:00:11:44:3f: (1131583)
```

Cannot reproduce, and `00:00:00:00:00:11:44:3f:` is not a little-endian representation of 1131583. It is a *big*-endian representation of 1131583. As a little-endian number it is a rather large number: 4347598471168.

What this code *actually* produces on the wire, as printed by

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    {
        public void write(byte[] bytes)  throws IOException
        {
            for (byte b : bytes)
            {
                System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff)+":");
            }
            System.out.println();
            super.write(bytes);
        }
    };
```

is:

```
46:49:4c:45:
92:44:11:0:0:0:0:0:
// etc.
```

There is no problem with this code.

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry, I forgot I changed it to big-endian to see if there was any change.